# SharePoint display template not showing in site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, display-template

[image]I've just created a copy of a display template in SharePoint and made a change to the styling then checked-it back in.

I've also made sure that the Result Type is associate with the Display Template and then linked that to the search result for the WebPart.

However, the site still shows the old template. I've restarted the web site in IIS and it still shows the old template.

Comment: Did you publish a new major version and check it in after the changes?

Comment: Please see above image. I think the problem is I've made a copy of the SharePoint Community template. But there is some issue with the associations as it uses Result Types not a single template. When testing this if I swap to using a Single Template using the Community Item the template is NOT the same! Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever we create any display template we required two of the operation to be performed.

- Check-In the template
- Publish the template as Major version

It seems that you have already Check-In the template. So what you need is that publish the template as major version.

Comment: The template has been checked-in and I can see a major version in the version history. It also has 'approved' next to the list in Design Manager: Edit Display Templates. Still no sign of updated mark-up on the default home page for the Web Part that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

Publish a major version of the template